# Can I use javascript to paste into an input field onClick

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, copy-paste, paste

Another user helped me with this nice script that allows me to click a table cell and its contents will copy to the clipboard. I don't fully understand it, but it works...  I want to add something to this program now.  Here’s the original program first..

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let target = e.target;

  if(target.localName === 'td') {
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(target);  
  let sel= document.getSelection(); 
  sel.removeAllRanges(); 
  sel.addRange(range); 
  document.execCommand('copy');
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  target.classList.add('copy-animate');
  setTimeout(() => {target.classList.remove('copy-animate');}, 300);
  }
});
```

```css
.copy-animate {background:#F00}
td {cursor:pointer;border:1px solid black}
input {border:1px solid black;width:200px}
```

```html
Click a table cell to copy<br>
<table><td>milk</td><td>bread</td><td>eggs</td><td>cheese</td></table>

<br>This is the pasting area.  Try pasting here.<br>
<input type="text">
```

The program above listens for a click on a TD and copies it.  I now want to have it listen for a click on an INPUT and if that occurs, do a paste. I thought I could just add a similar IF statement like the one below, but it didn't work.  Please help.  So the end result should allow me to copy from a table cell to the input field with just two clicks.  I don't want to have to right click and select paste from the menu, or use CTRL-V.

```
 if(target.localName === 'input') {
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(target);  
  let sel= document.getSelection(); 
  sel.removeAllRanges(); 
  sel.addRange(range); 
  document.execCommand('paste');
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  }
```

Comment: What if you tried, target.tagName?

Comment: I new to javascript, so I really don't know how to add this feature to the program.

Comment: Replace target.localName with target.tagName and see what you get.

Comment: That didn't help

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can’t programmatically do a paste in js. It’s a security measure.

What you could do instead is keep track of the element that has focus and listen for a copy event. Then you can check the input value or innerHTML of the original element and get the contents that way to put into the target element.

Comment: Actually, you can trigger a [paste event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/ClipboardEvent) programmatically, but you won't have access to the user's clipboard's data, you will have to populate this event's data yourself, programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't programatically paste into an input. But for testing it's usually enough to simulate the JS event that would be triggered if a user had pasted.

Here's a full example of creating and triggering a `paste` event.

```js
const text = 'pasted text';
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.setData('text', text);
const event = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
  clipboardData: dataTransfer,
  bubbles: true
});
const element = document.querySelector('input');
element.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Note there's also a new [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) that lets pages request access to read a user's clipboard data.

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work, nothing was pasted into the input value